# API do Instagram necessita de access token para obter dados publicos

Tags: php, api, instagram-api

Preciso consumir a [API do Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) para procurar posts com um conjunto de hashtag e extrair as seguintes informações:

- Utilizador
- Número de likes
- Número de seguidores
- Data do post

Entretanto a partir de Jul/2016 será necessário utilizar um access token para obter os dados públicos do utilizador.

O problema é que atualmente é preciso apenas o `client_id` para obter as informações, então configurei um cronjob que executa um script que por sua vez faz a chamada a API e grava os dados na base de dados.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag}/media/recent?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>
```

Entretanto com a nova API é necessário obter um access token e isso é manual, o cliente precisa autorizar o acesso aos dados.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag}/media/recent?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Com essa nova API, o cliente terá sempre que autorizar a aplicação?

Se sim, isso não faz sentido se os dados são públicos.

Comment: Olá Filipe Moraes, estou com o mesmo problema, você já encontrou alguma solução?

Comment: @LeonardoRocha não estou nem conseguindo aprovar uma app para fazer testes com dados de produção e tentar obter uma resposta. Infelizmente complicaram muito.

Comment: Complicado. Obrigado pela resposta.